# GoogleMaps, Reverse geocode, return street_address

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have a form that allows the user to create a new marker on the Google Map, with an infoWindow containing info the user provides.  One field allows the user to enter a description of the location (i.e. "Buds Burgers on Sonoma in Vallejo") and a marker will be created with the exact same info in what I have labeled as "Location.address".  My goal is to reverse geocode the given coordinates and output the street address for any location provided. I am able to console.log the lat and lng so I know that I can access them, I just haven't been able to figure out how do I use them.

location.rb

```
create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "location_name"
    t.string   "location_address"
    t.string   "location_description"
    t.float    "lat"
    t.float    "lng"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end
```

The script running on my map page:

```
<script>
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.725685, -122.156830),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

      var places = <%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng),
        map: map
        });
        var lat = (places[i].lat);
        var lng = (places[i].lng);

        console.log(" lat: " +  places[i].lat + " " + "lng: " + places[i].lng);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(places[i].location_name + "   <br />  " + places[i].location_description  + "    <br />     " + places[i].location_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }
</script>
```

Form:

```
 <%= form_for @location, :html => { :class => "form-inline" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :location_name %><br />

  <%= f.label "Description or Discount Offered" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :location_description %><br />

  <%= f.label :address %>:
  <%= f.text_field :location_address %><br />

  <%= f.submit "Create New Location"%>
 <% end %>
```

I am at my wits end.  Help please.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the geocoding documentation?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Yes.  That along with youtube, other postings and google searches.  The docs are how I got this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with **Ruby-on-Rails** but I can definitely help you in Google Maps API. Let's just use coordinates **places[i].lat** and **places[i].lng** since you said in your post that you can log their values.

You wanted to Reverse Geocode the coordinates you acquired.

> **[Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)**
>   is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a
>   human-readable address.

Let's start by creating a new Geocoder instance.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

This means that a new instance of Geocoder Object has been created using variable "geocoder". You can now use Geocoder's **geocode method**.

In **Reverse Geocoding**, **geocode method** accepts 2 arguments - location, and callback. You need to use "location" parameter and supply a comma-separated latitude/longitude or you can simply use **new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)** object. The value of this should be the coordinates you acquired.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'location' : new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng) }, callback );
```

On the other hand, the callback arguments need two arguments as well. The first is for the result, and the other is for the status. You can name the arguments, whatever you want. This is where most of our logic will be implemented.

```
function(results, status) {
   if ( status === 'OK' ) {
   } 
}
```

In the callback function, there's should be a condition that checks if the returned status is **'OK'**. If so, the **results** arguments will return an array of results. There's a note in **Reverse Geocoding** documentation:

> The reverse geocoder often returns more than one result.  Geocoded
>   addresses are not just postal addresses, but any way to geographically
>   name a location.

You can get the formatted address under **results[0].formatted_address**. You can also get address_components such as "**street_number**", "**route**", "**locality**", and "**country**" and append it to the DOM. I recommend using an external library using **[JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/)** to make DOM manipulation easier. You can do something like this:

```
function(results, status) {
   if ( status === 'OK' ) {
   $('div#street_name').html('<p>'+results[0].formatted_address.+'</p>');
   } 
}
```

The whole code looks something like this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'location' : new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng) }, function(results, status) {
   if ( status === 'OK' ) {
   $('div#street_name').html('<p>'+results[0].formatted_address.+'</p>');
   } 
});
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you that helped a great deal.  I am just wondering why the formatted_address is just giving me the city and state.  When I create a new location, it correctly places the marker, but I can't seem to find the street address in the object/data for me to access and display.  Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please give me what json do you see when you return the results? And also your query.

Comment: It's working now.  I had to use "results[0].formatted_address" and I got the street address.  Thanks again.  I was mis-typing.